# Populating a volume using a container does not work in Docker on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-volume

I'm following the instruction on this Docker official page under ["Populate a volume using a container"](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container) in an attempt to create a new volume populated with existing files in a newly launched container. I ran the following command, expecting the existing files and folders under **C:\Data** on the container to be available under the volume:

```
docker run -it --name=test -v C:\Data dataimage/test1:version1
```

A new volume appears to be created successfully. However, navigating to **C:\Data** folder on the container shows that it is completely empty. If I run the above command without the `-v option` instead, then I can see the original files at the same location.

Is this a fully supported feature in Docker on Windows? If so, could someone please shed a light on what I may be doing wrong?

I am using Docker Engine version is v19.03.8. And my host OS is Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker run -it --name=test -v '/c/Data:/data' dataimage/test1:version1
```

That should sync the `C:\Data` folder on your windows host with the `/data` folder in the container. If `/data` isn't the folder name you want in the container, change as needed.

Comment: There might have been a bit of confusion. "dataimage/test1:version1" is actually the name of the image I was using, **C:\Data** is the path within the container at which I am trying to create a volume.

Comment: @Yoshi aha, gotcha. Updated my answer. 

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) It actually didn't work unfortunately.

I think this is not quite what I am aiming for either actually. In my understanding, the syntax you suggested is for bind mount where you create a mapping between a host's local file system and a container's. What I actually want to do is to have a volume created and populated with existing content of a container. I then want to access that volume from yet another container (not mentioned above) using `--volumes-from` option.